# How to show a stutter in dialogue?

Tags: dialogue

I have seen different ways of showing a stutter in dialogue - an em dash, just saying it was stuttered, etc. What other ways of showing a stutter are there?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question: [Dash and space usage for dialogue interruptions, stuttering, starting over](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/31775/dash-and-space-usage-for-dialogue-interruptions-stuttering-starting-over)

Comment: For the record, if you're talking about the speech disorder, I think the more interesting question is how you would show a stutter _outside_ of dialogue.